# swift - trying to update UILabel with delegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uilabel

I´m trying to update my `@IBOutlet weak var gameclockLabel: UILabel!` from my `class Gameclock` with delegate.
I have read and tested about a million different ways but can't make it work. I think that the more I read about it the more confused I get.

You can read more about what I'm trying to do here:
[swift invalidate timer in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35812832/swift-invalidate-timer-in-function)

From the answers in that question I added this: `var gameClock = Gameclock()` so I was able to start a function in `class Gameclock` and first I tried to do the same with my  `class ViewController: UIViewController` but that didn't work so that's why I decided to try with delegate instead. Do you think delegate is the right way to go with this?

I'm going to add several timers in separate classes to this later on so perhaps there's a better way.

Would be nice if someone could point me in the right direction. At first I thought this would be not to complicated but seems I was mistaking  :)

The complete code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

protocol test1: class {
func updateLabel()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, test1 {

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    gameclockLabel.text = "00:00"
}

var gameClock = Gameclock()
var startstopPushed: Bool = false

@IBOutlet weak var gameclockLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var startstop: UIButton!
@IBAction func startStopbutton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if startstopPushed == false {

        gameClock.startGameclock()
        startstop.setImage(UIImage(named: "stop.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        startstopPushed = true
    }
    else
    {
        gameClock.stopGameclock()
        startstop.setImage(UIImage(named: "start.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        startstopPushed = false
    }
}
func updateLabel() {
    print("updated")
    gameclockLabel.text = gameClock.timeString
}
}

class Gameclock : NSObject {

var gameclockTimer = NSTimer()
var timeString: String = ""
var seconds = 0
var minutes = 0
weak var delegate: test1?

func startGameclock() {
    print("start")
    gameclockTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateGameclock"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func stopGameclock() {
    self.gameclockTimer.invalidate()
    print("stopp")
}

func updateGameclock() {

    seconds += 1
    if seconds == 60 {
        minutes += 1
        seconds = 0
    }

    let secondsString = seconds > 9 ? "\(seconds)" : "0\(seconds)"
    let minutesString = minutes > 9 ? "\(minutes)" : "0\(minutes)"

    timeString = "\(minutesString):\(secondsString)"
    print(timeString)

    delegate?.updateLabel()
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't actually set your `ViewController` instance as your `GameClock`s delegate, so your `updateLabel` method won't be called;

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    gameclockLabel.text = "00:00"
    self.gameClock.delegate=self
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Paul! Works perfect now :D